# proper scm for a static website deployed to a storage account?

Tags: azure

Can you point me to a url which describes proper SCM for a Static Website deployed to a Storage Account?  I have a ReactJS website deployed as a static website to an Azure Storage Account.  Currently I'm just pushing updated deployments via an Azure extension in VS Code.

Separately, I have an App Service which has an associated Deployment Center with a configured Pipeline and its own Azure DevOps source code repo.  The App Service setup as I've described seems to have at least a decent start on some semblance of SCM.

When viewing the webpage for a storage account in the Azure portal, I don't see a "Deployment Center" left nav item like I do for an App Service in the portal.  In the Azure portal, looks like a storage account can only have a single static website b/c "static website" exists as a single left nav item for a particular storage account page in the Azure portal.  If I click on the "static website" left nav item for my deployed ReactJS app, I don't see any type of additional hook into the Deployment Center.  A "git status" on my local code folder indicates that the folder is not a git repo.

So I'd like to get my static website code into an Azure DevOps repo.  I need the code to be source-controlled and since my App Service is in an Azure DevOps repo, I'd like the same for my static website code for consistency.  I'm also assuming that the code needs to be in an Azure DevOps repo in order to easily and fully leverage Azure DevOps functionality like pipelines, etc.

So can you advise how I can get from point A to point B for this scenario or if there may be constraints or alternatives with what I'm trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `Azure File Copy task` to push the build artifacts to Blob Storage. From the documentation link:

> Use this task in a build or release pipeline to copy files to
>   Microsoft Azure storage blobs or virtual machines (VMs).
>
> The task is used to copy application files and other artifacts that
>   are required in order to install the app; such as PowerShell scripts,
>   PowerShell-DSC modules, and more.

You would need to push the artifacts to `$web` blob container as this container is used to serve static website.

You can learn more about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-file-copy?view=azure-devops